# How can I return the numeric value of a React container instead of an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn React and am working on a simple web app to implement what I've learned online so far.

I have a container called `CardDatabase.js` and all it returns is a single value. This value is called `reduceArray` and it's an array that has had the `reduce()` method called on it. When I render `<CardDatabase.js />` the value appears in the browser and in the console as intended (in the screenshot, it's 86). However, when I try to assign the value of `<CardDatabase />` to variable `w` inside of the `calculate` method in `App.js`, an object is returned instead of a numeric value (check the console in the screenshot).

[image]

**How can I assign the numeric value of `<CardDatabase />` to a variable so that I can use it to calculate some simple math?**

I also tried using props and `this.state` but according to the console error I got and the React docs, we cannot modify the value of props? So when I tried something like:

```
const array = (rarityOfArray) => {
        filteredArray = rarityOfArray.filter(item => item.key <= level)

        for(let x = 0; x < filteredArray.length; x++) {
            pushedArray.push(filteredArray[x].cardsRequiredToUpgrade)
            console.log(pushedArray);
        }

        props.array = pushedArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        console.log("Reduced - " + reducedArray);

        return props.array
    }
```

I got this error message: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'array' of object '#<Object>'`

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

// CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

// Components 
import CardRarityDropdown from './components/CardRarityDropdown';
import CardLevelDropdown from './components/CardLevelDropdown';
import CardAmountInput from './components/CardAmountInput';
import CardCalculationsButton from './components/CardCalculationsButton';

//Containers
import CardDatabase from './containers/cardDatabase/CardDatabase';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cardRarity: "",
      cardLevel: "",
      amountOfCards: "",
    }
    this.setCardValues = this.setCardValues.bind(this);
  }

  setCardValues = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target

    this.setState({
          [name]: value
    })
  }

  calculate = () => {
    let v = this.state.cardRarity;
    console.log("v: " + v)

    let w = <CardDatabase />
    console.log("w: " + w)

    let x = v - w;
    console.log("x: " + x)

    let y = this.state.amountOfCards;
    console.log("y: " + y)

    let z = x - y;
    console.log("z: " + z)

    return z
  }

  render () {
    return (

        <div>
          <h1 id="superCellText">Clash Royale Card Calculator</h1>

          <CardRarityDropdown
            setCardValues={this.setCardValues}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity} />

          <CardLevelDropdown
            setCardValues={this.setCardValues}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity}
            cardLevel={this.state.cardLevel} />

          <CardDatabase
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity}
            cardLevel={this.state.cardLevel} />

          <CardAmountInput
            setCardValues={this.setCardValues}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity}
            amountOfCards={this.state.amountOfCards} />

          <CardCalculationsButton
            calculate={this.calculate}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity} />
        </div> 
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**CardDatabase.js**

```
import common from './Common';
import rare from './Rare';
import epic from './Epic';
import legendary from './Legendary';


const CardDatabase = (props) => {

    const card = props.cardRarity;
    const level = props.cardLevel;
    let filteredArray = [];
    let pushedArray = [];
    let reducedArray = [];

    const array = (rarityOfArray) => {
        filteredArray = rarityOfArray.filter(item => item.key <= level)

        for(let x = 0; x < filteredArray.length; x++) {
            pushedArray.push(filteredArray[x].cardsRequiredToUpgrade)
            console.log(pushedArray);
        }

        reducedArray = pushedArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        console.log("Reduced - " + reducedArray);

        return reducedArray
    }

    if(card === "9586") {return array(common)}

    if(card === "2586") {return array(rare)}

    if(card === "386") {return array(epic)}

    if(card === "36") {return array(legendary)}

    if(card === "")  {return null}
}
export default CardDatabase;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks on Reddit and Discord were giving me the same feedback, I shouldn't be using a component if said component isn't returning anything UI-related. Therefore, `CardDatabase.js` shouldn't be a component but a simple function instead.

I changed its name to `cardDatabase.js` so that React no longer considers it a component and instead of it receiving props, the function now has standard parameters.

**Updated cardDatabase.js**

```
import common from './Common';
import rare from './Rare';
import epic from './Epic';
import legendary from './Legendary';


const cardDatabase = (cardRarity, cardLevel) => {

    let filteredArray = [];
    let pushedArray = [];
    let reducedArray = [];

    const array = (rarityOfArray) => {
        filteredArray = rarityOfArray.filter(item => item.key <= cardLevel)

        for(let x = 0; x < filteredArray.length; x++) {
            pushedArray.push(filteredArray[x].cardsRequiredToUpgrade)
            console.log(pushedArray);
        }

        reducedArray = pushedArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        console.log("Reduced - " + reducedArray);

        return reducedArray
    }

    if(cardRarity === "9586") {return array(common)}

    if(cardRarity === "2586") {return array(rare)}

    if(cardRarity === "386") {return array(epic)}

    if(cardRarity === "36") {return array(legendary)}

    if(cardRarity === "")  {return null}
}
export default cardDatabase;
```

In `App.js` I removed the `<CardDatabase />` component and inside of my `calculate` method, simply assigned the value of variable `w` to my `cardDatabase` function with `this.state.cardRarity` and `this.state.cardLevel` as the arguments.

**Updated App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

// CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

// Components 
import CardRarityDropdown from './components/CardRarityDropdown';
import CardLevelDropdown from './components/CardLevelDropdown';
import CardAmountInput from './components/CardAmountInput';
import CardCalculationsButton from './components/CardCalculationsButton';

//Containers
import cardDatabase from './containers/cardDatabase/cardDatabase.js';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cardRarity: "",
      cardLevel: "",
      amountOfCards: "",
    }
    this.setCardValues = this.setCardValues.bind(this);
  }

  setCardValues = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target

    this.setState({
          [name]: value
    })
  }

  calculate = () => {
    let rarity = this.state.cardRarity;
    let level = this.state.cardLevel;
    console.log("v: " + rarity)

    let w = cardDatabase(rarity, level);
    console.log("w: " + w)

    let x = rarity - w;
    console.log("x: " + x)

    let y = this.state.amountOfCards;
    console.log("y: " + y)

    let z = x - y;
    console.log("z: " + z)

    return z
  }

  render () {
    return (

        <div>
          <h1 id="superCellText">Clash Royale Card Calculator</h1>

          <CardRarityDropdown
            setCardValues={this.setCardValues}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity} />

          <CardLevelDropdown
            setCardValues={this.setCardValues}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity}
            cardLevel={this.state.cardLevel} />

          <CardAmountInput
            setCardValues={this.setCardValues}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity}
            amountOfCards={this.state.amountOfCards} />

          <CardCalculationsButton
            calculate={this.calculate}
            cardRarity={this.state.cardRarity} />
        </div> 
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Now `w` is returning a numerical value instead of an object and my app is finally functioning properly.

[image]